# Automatically upload javascript and css to S3 on local file change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, codekit

Is there a way that when working on a project locally I can use my cdn links by auto-uploading the changed files upon save to my S3 bucket? I've looked online and can't find anything that will do what I need.

I was hoping maybe there would be a codekit plugin but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Write your own CodeKit hook (https://codekitapp.com/help/hooks/) that calls awscli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing a shell file and running the `aws s3 cp` command I'm able to upload my files to S3. I link this as a codekit hook like @jarmod said.

```
# Upload
aws s3 cp localfile s3://bucket/directory/
```